# ola-hallengren running full backups and log backups at the same time-- restore issues?

Tags: sql-server, ola-hallengren

I recently ran across an issue trying to restore a db and log files.  DB restored without issues.  About 10 log files in, I received a message stating the LSN was out of sync and could not finish.  I used a tool that puts them in order, so that's not my issue.   I have my log backups set to run in 15 minute intervals.  This large database takes a couple of hours to perform a full backup. Could the log backups happening simultaneously during the full backup cause this situation?

The end result was not bad this time, but this is alarming.  I am trying to maintain a RPO of 15 minutes.
This little test resulted in an 8 hr RPO.... unacceptable.

Regards,

Tim

Answer (score 0):

> Could the log backups happening simultaneously during the full backup
> cause this situation?

No, simultaneous full and log backups have been possible since `SQL Server 2005`, as [Paul Randal](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/author/paul/) states here in a [post on concurrent log / full backups](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/search-engine-qa-16-concurrent-log-and-full-backups/).

> Here’s a question that came in – what changed in SQL Server 2005 that
> allows concurrent log and full backups?
>
> In SQL Server 2005, the restriction was lifted, but there’s a subtle
> twist. You can do concurrent log backups with fulls BUT the log is not
> cleared when the log backup ends. The clearing of the inactive portion
> of the log is delayed until the full backup completes. This could
> cause you to have disk space problems if your log generation rate is
> huge and you’re relying on very frequent backups to manage the log
> size.

Also stated [here](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/a-sql-server-dba-myth-a-day-3030-backup-myths/) regarding the many myths regardings backups.

> I used a tool that puts them in order, so that's not my issue

If it is not the tool's wrong doing as you mention then I would try to look if there are any other log backups being taken in your backup history dmv's in the `MSDB` database.

Double check the restore procedure as well so that you are certain that you have all the log files (*for example different paths after failing over the Always On Availability Group if the database is participating in an Availability Group, however Ola's procedure should take care of that*).

Comment: Thanks Randi.   I ran the query you suggested and see that after the full backup, several log backups are created that look normal.  Then I see one with a NUL physical device name  (no file location, but has a backup size) followed by other normal log backups.  Oddly, I was able to restore the one right after the null entry.  But the 2nd one after the NUL entry failed with an out of sequence message.

Comment: @TimShelton this should be the issue then, I am not sure why one of these did not give the error however. Best to investigate if there is some process backing up the `LOG to 'NUL'` and breaking the log chain.